# Mulberry new growth leaves curling down

Tags: trees, leaves, mulberry

My mulberry tree leaves are curling fully or partially from the new growth. I can see it right now in 1/3 of the branches. There are no insects near or on the leaves. I water every 3rd day about 100 litter as it is sandy soil and tree trunk is about 1.5 to 2 inch.

There are actually 2 mulberry trees, same size, same soil, same care routine. One is fine, but only this one has the problem. What could be the reason?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry. just curious, how old and how tall is your tree?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur Planted a 1-year-old tree in May this year. It is about 15 feet tall. I have also added another photo above.